# Получить user data в Hook Proc

Tags: c++, winapi

Я имею класс следующего вида:

```
class Hook
{
public:
    static LRESULT WINAPI HookProc(int, WPARAM, LPARAM);
...
}
```

Он находится в dll(будет экспортируемым). Соответственно HookProc является процедурой хука.
В приложении я создаю хук на клавиатуру. В самой процедуре хука я хотел бы иметь доступ к членам класса. В случае с WndProc есть замечательный способ с :

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)класс);
```

Каким способом я могу передать пользовательские данные в эту процедуру? Был ещё вариант с помощью WM_COPYDATA, но нужно снова знать HWND назначения..а у хука нет HWND.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. через глобальную переменную
2. через сгенерированный санк (то бишь тело функции обратного вызова генерируется во время работы программы с зашитыми праметрами)

Comment: 1 - точно нет, ибо стараюсь придерживаться строго ООП
2 - можно подробнее, не совсем понятно

Comment: @Range https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507193/callback-of-member-functions-through-3d-party-library/11507789#11507789

Comment: @zenden2k перешёл по ссылке, там приводилась ссылка на CodeProject. Просто замечательная, отличная статья! Всё получилось.